# Android ProgressBar when activity is starting

Tags: java, android

I want to create loading progress bar when my activity is starting. I have an activity with ViewFlipper which contains `OpenStreetMap` and `GridView`  (I'm switching this two views using `ViewVlipper` ). I want to display loading progress bar just like Foursquare does. I have some SQL queries which are executing for 0.1 - 0.3s but I want my app to be really responsive ;-). I know  that I should use `AsyncTask` and PostExecute etc. But... how can I obtain similar effect to Foursquare app?

What should I move to the postExecute method? Adding adapter with items which were queried from database to the GridView and adding pins to the map? Any ideas how should  it should be done?

[image: Foursquare loading]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many ways to accomplish this, but one of the easiest may simply be to toggle the visibility of a `ProgressBar` that is defined in your XML layout (one that fills the parent view).

I've done this in AsyncTasks where I show the `ProgressBar` in `onPreExecute()` and the remove it in `onPostExecute()` with `setVisibility(View.GONE)`.

Comment: is it possible that we can implement the same without an AsyncTasks..? if so could you please explain that or give the syntax.

Answer (score -2):

Try adding a WebView with an animated GIF progress indicator to your Activity. Make sure the WebView is the only View visible in your Activity at first, then hide it (set setVisibility(View.GONE)) when you're ready.

Comment: No need to use a WebView for this. Better to use a built in ProgressBar, or even an animated Drawable.